# React Router v6 navigater() has to be called twice for loader to respond

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React router with a loader set up.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/blog/:id", // root path
    action, // handles form payloads
    loader, // handles page loads
    errorElement: <Error />,
  },
]);
```

The loader simply logs the parameters passed through,

```
export const loader = async ({ request, params }) => {
  console.log(params);
  return params;
};
```

Then I have a button with an `onClick` parameter with a `useNavigate()` hook. When pressed, the URL does update as expected. However, the console does not log anything.

If I click the button one more time, the console will log the parameters `{id: 1}`.

```
<Dropdown.Item
  onClick={() =>
    navigate(`/blog/1/}`)
  }
>
```

Any ideas as to why the `navigate()` function updates the URL, but requires a second call for the loader function to run? If I refresh the page with the new URL, the loader runs immediately. But through the `navigate()` call, it requires two clicks.

I simplified this example, but in my actual app, the UI also renders as it should upon the second click, pulling in the blog post, same as it does when I refresh the page in my browser.

I am running this through `npm start` and this is not the post-build. Doesn't have to do with `React.StrictMode` does it?

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the code snippet you've shared. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese I can give it a shot in a bit if this doesn't get any traction. I tried creating a build and running it through an Express server and the issue persists, so likely not anything to do with React's strict mode.

Comment: @DrewReese I tried to recreate the example but am having issues with it even rendering that. Not sure what I am missing here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-marco-vmf8lh

Comment: How accurate is the route/UI structure/organization in the sandbox to your real code? I made a few changes (`button` element instead of `Link` component, `HomePage` component to render `Outlet` for nested route, etc.) and the loader function is called and logs the route path params as I'd expect.

Comment: Can you share a link? When I visit my own link, it's my last renditions to the code. And I'd say structurally it is quite similar. But I cannot see the changes you made.

Comment: Sure, check forked [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-navigater-has-to-be-called-twice-for-loader-to-respond-etritt).

Comment: I added `{Object.values(loaderData).join(" ")}` to my <Root /> element in my own code. I actually do see the loader function firing off `console.log()` functions, but the `useEffect(() => {}, [loaderData])` is not being triggered, and the loaderData.join() is not rendering new text.

Seems like the loader is not trickling down to the child element after initial load?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for the updates. I can see your code now. Looks good from my end, though I am struggling to ascertain a difference between this and what my source code is. The children paths are actually not meant to render any new elements, they're just additional paths for the root element to work with. So I added them as children but with no element. Is this an okay approach? I didn't see a way to assign multiple routes to the root element through an array or anything.

Comment: I fixed the loader not firing by assigning the same loader to the children. I figured the loader applied to children automatically, but evidently not? But that does not seem to have any effect on the useLoaderData() hook not updating.

Comment: Good news, fixed it. Posting my solution in a moment!

Comment: The loader functions are per `Route` that is rendered, and there can be only one `Route` per path within a `Routes`/parent `Route` component.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you. You helped point me in the right direction with your code demo. Please take a look at my answer, feel free to comment there if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so my example was not going to be very helpful, but here is what my problem was...

I have a one-page application, and it's a form. I thought if I wanted to add more paths for the same form to accept, I would add those paths/routes as children to the main element in the router. However, since the target element (the form) is the exact same, I should not have been using children.

Children are for when you want to *render* things for a specific path *inside* of a root element. Maybe that should have been obvious to me.

Trying to pass down the same loader to the children does not seem to happen automatically. So I tried assigning the loader to each child, but it was still counter to purpose of children, as I mentioned earlier. It was causing weird rendering issues.

Anyways, so what I did instead was I built an array of routes I want assigned to this one element, and mapped them out as root-level paths of the same object properties.

```
const element = (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Container className="gx-0 mx-lg-0 mb-5 overflow-hidden" fluid>
        <div className="d-flex">
          <div className="d-none d-lg-block">
            <Menu />
          </div>
          <div className="flex-grow-1 pe-lg-5 ps-lg-0 px-5">
            <Form />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </>
  );

  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    ["/", "form/:formFieldValue"].map((path) => ({
      path,
      action,
      loader,
      element,
      errorElement: <Error />,
    }))
  );
```

et voilá! The navigate() commands work, loader is assigned to each route, useLoaderData() is updating and firing off the useEffect hook as a dependency.